# Include references in executable

Tags: c#, com, resources, unpack

This is for C#.

I know that I can include a COM File as a resource in my executable and then unpack it into the current directory when its needed. A com file such as LibCurlNet.

What I would like to know is if Visual C# 2010 Express provides an automated way of doing this.
Such as a simple option that I can select. I do not mean using the publisher.

Comment: It is completely automatic when you use a Setup project.  Also takes care of the problem of not being able to write to c:\program files.

Answer (score 0):

I don't even think there is an automated way in Visual Studio Professional/Ultimate for doing this, let alone VS Express. You probably need to use a more manual approach, such as the one described [here](http://codeblog.larsholm.net/2011/06/embed-dlls-easily-in-a-net-assembly/) (but I guess you already knew that).

There is a tool for packing .NET DLL:s and native DLL:s called [NETZ](http://madebits.com/netz/index.php). Granted, I have not tried it myself, but maybe this tool can be of some help to you?